# How can I get src of video from HTML

Tags: php, html

on example.com is `<video>` like:

```
<video controls="" preload="false" src="http://example.com/video.mp4"></video>
```

and I would like to get content of `src=""` which is inside of that `<video>` tag

(example.com is not my website, I need to use PHP to get to the HTML code and get the src from the video tag)

thank you!

Comment: Where do you want to get the SRC? by javascript or by php?

Comment: PHP is best in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty way

```
<?php
preg_match_all('#<video .*?src="(.*?)"#', file_get_contents('https://example.com'), $results);

print_r($results[1]);
```

A better way is to use web scraping/crawling tools like [FriendsOfPHP/Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte)

Comment: I ended up with simplehtmldom but your solution is way easier & faster for my simple usage

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get any value in php you have to do an [Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call and send the data:

```
   $('#element').click(function({
             var src = $(this).attr('src');
             $.ajax({
                url:'/someFile.php/ajax/',
                type:'post',
                dataType:'json',
                data:{
                    src:src;
                },
                success:function(data){
                   console.log('src sended');
                }
             });
         });
```

You can also do it entirely in PHP with https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/